# throw APIException Facebook api php

Tags: php, facebook, exception

I'd like to get my api exception but I don't understand how to do that.
This is my code

```
public function facebook($link){

    if(!$link || !trim($link) != ""){
        return false;
    }

    $config = array(
            'appId'=>$this->keys['facebook']['id'],
            'secret'=>$this->keys['facebook']['secret'],
            'fileUpload'=>false
    );

    $facebook = new Facebook($config);


    $start = strrpos($link, '/', -1);
    $end = strripos($link, '?', -1);
    $end = ($end)?$end:strlen($link);

    $pageId = ($end == strlen($link))?substr($link, $start + 1):substr($link, $start + 1, $end - strlen($link));

    try {
        $pagefeed = $facebook->api("/" . $pageId . "/feed");
    }
    catch (FacebookApiException $e){
        return false;
    }

    //set datetime
    foreach ($pagefeed['data'] as $key => $post){
        $pagefeed['data'][$key]['datetime'] = new \DateTime($post['created_time']);
    }

    return $pagefeed;
}
```

So I'd like to return false in case of exception.

I got for exemple:

```
BaseFacebook ->throwAPIException (array('error' => array('message' => '(#803) Some of the aliases you requested do not exist: lkdsgfkqdjgflkdshbf', 'type' => 'OAuthException', 'code' => '803')))
```

Thanks for your help

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Since you've commented that you're using symfony, and you fixed the type-hint using `catch(\Exception $e)` you might want to consider adding this to the top of your file:

```
use \APIException;
```

To set `APIException` as an alias to `\APIException`. [Also check this link](http://dev.dbl-a.com/php/symfony2-and-facebook-authentication/). Not having used the FB API, I don't know if it's still relevant, but assuming the facebook api is stored in your vendor dir, you'll have to specify the correct namespaces when using the Facebook api.
The reason why `\Exception` worked is simply because, as the linked page shows, the `APIException` class extends from the `\Exception` base-class, so the type-hint works. It's not crucial, but it's generally better to catch the right exception in the right place.

The Exception is thrown, and you catch it using the `catch` block. So far so good, it is, though, caught in the method's scope, which is GC'ed when that method returns (Garbage Collected). The `Exception` isntance doesn't exits anymore.
Generally, if you want to access the exception outside of the method (most likely in the code that invoked the method), you just don't catch the exception. Remove the `try-catch` from the `facebook` method and do this:

```
//call method:
try
{
    $return = $instance->facebook($someLink);
}
catch (APIException $e)
{
    $return = false;//exception was thrown, so the return value should be false
    var_dump($e);//you have access to the exception here, too
}
```

Catching an exception and not doing anything with it (you're catching but returning false, no way of knowing *why*) is considered bad practice.
If you want to avoid wrapping all those calls to your `facebook` method in a try-catch, you could do something like this, too:

```
//in class containing facebook method:
private $lastException = null;
public function getLastException()
{
    return $this->lastException;
}
```

Now you can change your `facebook` method's catch block to:

```
catch(APIException $e)
{
    $this->lastException = $e;
    return false;
}
```

And do something like:

```
$return = $instance->facebook($link);
if ($return === false)
{
    var_dump($instance->getLastException());
    exit($instance->getLastException()->getMessage());
}
```

Comment: Thanks for your answer, but I don't really understand why the exception isn't thrown in my case, my page return 500 Internal Server Error - FacebookApiException (I'm using Symfony2)

Comment: I find the solution, I had to catch \Exception with symfony

Comment: @ant: Added some more info on why `\Exception` worked for you (it's to do with namespaces and resolving the class-names)

Comment: I found the answer on this post http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5689415/symfony2-controller-wont-catch-exception
And \APIException or \FacebookAPIException didn't works

Comment: @ant: Sure, but it's pretty much the same thing as I added, only I've added the fact that you can avoid having to use that leading `\` all the time, simply by adding a `use \Exception;` to the top of your script. That means that, inside that class, `Exception` refers to the global `\Exception` class