# How to catch Exception in symfony 2?

Tags: php, symfony

How to Catch exception in the controller and show flash message in Symfony 2?

```
try{
  $em = $this->getDoctrine()->getManager();
  $em->persist($entity);
  $em->flush();

  return $this->redirect($this->generateUrl('target page'));
} catch(\Exception $e){
  // What to do in this part???
}

return $this->render('MyTestBundle:Article:new.html.twig', array(
  'entity' => $entity,
  'form'   => $form->createView(),
));
```

What should I do in the `catch` block?

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5689415/symfony2-controller-wont-catch-exception

Comment: toString($e) is not working. It shows
FatalErrorException: Error: Call to undefined function toString()

Comment: `echo (string)$e;` or better, send you an email on a productive site: `mail('you@x.com', 'Exception in script ...', var_export($e, true));`

Answer (score 16, accepted):

You should take care for the exceptions that could be raised:

```
public function postAction(Request $request)
{
  // ...

  try{
    $em = $this->getDoctrine()->getManager();
    $em->persist($entity);
    $em->flush();

    return $this->redirect($this->generateUrl('target page'));

  } catch(\Doctrine\ORM\ORMException $e){
    // flash msg
    $this->get('session')->getFlashBag()->add('error', 'Your custom message');
    // or some shortcut that need to be implemented
    // $this->addFlash('error', 'Custom message');

    // error logging - need customization
    $this->get('logger')->error($e->getMessage());
    //$this->get('logger')->error($e->getTraceAsString());
    // or some shortcut that need to be implemented
    // $this->logError($e);

    // some redirection e. g. to referer
    return $this->redirect($request->headers->get('referer'));
  } catch(\Exception $e){
    // other exceptions
    // flash
    // logger
    // redirection
  }

  return $this->render('MyTestBundle:Article:new.html.twig', array(
    'entity' => $entity,
    'form'   => $form->createView(),
  ));
}
```

Comment: `getRequest` is Deprecated as of `Symfony 2.4` and Removed as of `Symfony 3.0`. Please consider some editing

Answer (score 3):

Read this carefully, Catching exceptions and generating an output in the twig is clearly decribed here. :)

http://symfony.com/doc/current/book/controller.html

further,

you can use this primitive method to get methods of a class:

```
print_r(get_class_methods($e))
```

or this to pretty print your object

```
\Doctrine\Common\Util\Debug::dump($e);
```