# how to handle errors in symfony2 and store error in custom table

Tags: php, symfony

How to handle errors in symfony2 using try catch and store the error in custom db table like we do in C#.

eg

```
try
{
     // code with exception.
}
catch(Exception ex)
{
    //get the error and store information in table
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use the PHP try-catch block to catch exceptions as you mentioned. You can have a look to this answer:
[How to catch Exception in symfony 2?](https://stackoverflow.com/a/20327783/3642160)

With this method you can catch exceptions for the given code block. If you want to catch all exceptions in generally, then you should write an `EventListener` class, that will be fired if any uncatched exception occurs.

In the Symfony2 cookbook there is an example of writing an exception handler class: [How to create an Event Listener](http://symfony.com/doc/current/cookbook/service_container/event_listener.html)

Comment: Thank you very much i will try both the steps you have stated above and let you if i have any doubts.

Comment: does eventListener does not work for fatelexception that accur in system.

Comment: From Symfony 2.3 there is a built-in component called Debug:
http://symfony.com/doc/master/components/debug/introduction.html
You can set up a function that handles errors and converts them to exceptions, and then you can catch theese FatalErrorExceptions.