# sym2 IF-statement gives error "call to undefined function"

Tags: php, symfony, datetime, if-statement

I have an issue with my IF-statement, apparently.

Inside a symfony2 controller I have the following PHP:

```
57   foreach($all as $t) {
58       if ( ($end == null) || ($t->getDate()->format('Y-m-d') <= $end->format("Y-m-d")) ) {
59           if ( ($start == null) || ($t->getDate()->format('Y-m-d') >= $start->format("Y-m-d")) ) {
60              $subset[] = $t;
61          }
62      }
63   }
```

I get this for an error message:

```
FatalErrorException: Error: Call to undefined function App\Bundle\Controller\ () in 
www/App/src/App/Bundle/Controller/TransactionController.php line 59
```

If I comment the second IF-statement out like this, it runs without errors.

```
foreach($all as $t) {
    if ( ($end == null) || ($t->getDate()->format('Y-m-d') <= $end->format("Y-m-d")) ) {
        /*
        if ( ($start == null) || ($t->getDate()->format('Y-m-d') >= $start->format("Y-m-d")) ) {    
            $subset[] = $t;
        }
        */
    }
}
```

So somewhere in my if statement it tries to run a sym2 controller? I am lost...

Both `$start` and `$end` are valid `DateTime` objects, so are each `$date` on the `$t` objects.

If I var_dump the variables just before the second if-condition they print:

start:
object(DateTime)#1149 (3) { ["date"]=> string(19) "2014-12-20 16:39:06" ["timezone_type"]=> int(3) ["timezone"]=> string(13) "Europe/Berlin" }

end:
object(DateTime)#1150 (3) { ["date"]=> string(19) "2015-01-19 16:39:06" ["timezone_type"]=> int(3) ["timezone"]=> string(13) "Europe/Berlin" }

t->getDate():
object(DateTime)#1046 (3) { ["date"]=> string(19) "2012-12-11 00:00:00" ["timezone_type"]=> int(3) ["timezone"]=> string(13) "Europe/Berlin" }

Comment: The exception is odd.  Normally, it'd read like `undefined function App\Bundle\Controller\foo()`.  That blank between the namespace and the parentheses concerns me.  Would you please wrap the condition in a `try/catch` and paste the `var_dump()` of `$start`, `$end`, and `$t->getDate()` from inside the catch?

Comment: Where is your [testcase](http://sscce.org)?

Comment: I have no testcase, haven't learned about them. I var_dump():ed the variables just before the second if-condition (see above)

Comment: In order to do a try/catch in sym2 it appears I need to know the code/classname of the exact exception thrown (see this http://stackoverflow.com/questions/20325746/how-to-catch-exception-in-symfony-2) and I don't. tried with catch(exception as $e) and also tried catch(FatalErrorException as $e) but no success.

Comment: `catch (\Exception $ex) { var_dump($start, $end, $t->getDate()); }`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The error itself looks suspicious, with that whitespace between the namespace and parentheses:

```
Call to undefined function App\Bundle\Controller\ ()
```

Normally you'd expect to see something like:

```
Call to undefined function App\Bundle\Controller\foo_function()
```

Whatever is going on, PHP is seeing a "function" with a "blank" name.  I have encountered weird situations like this before, when I type really fast and happen to press a control character while inserting text.  It often happens around a space character, because on my keyboard the control character is next to the space bar.

Reproducing it will be next to impossible.  The best thing to do is just delete the line and retype it again, slowly.

If you're hell-bent on diagnosing it, then on GNU/Linux you can "take the cat to the vet":

```
$ cat file.php
<?php if (1 == 1) echo 'hi';

$ cat -vet file.php
<?php if (1 == ^@1) echo 'hi';
```

I used my editor to insert a null-byte in the if statement, which doesn't appear in normal inspection but does show when given to "the vet".

Answer (score 0):

So I don't know whether this is something symfony2 specific, but if I split the IF-condition into two different parts and thus do away with the OR operand || it actually works fine.

The puzzling part is that it didn't have a problem with the first IF-statement (which has a nearly identic condition).

```
                if ( $start == null ) {    
                    $subset[] = $t;
                }
                elseif ( $t->getDate()->format('Y-m-d') >= $start->format("Y-m-d") ) {
                    $subset[] = $t;
                }
```

Comment: I suspect you have (or had) a stray control character typed into your source somewhere in that branch.  Recombine them with the `||`, being careful on your typing :), and try again.

Comment: I think you are right. I did a copyPaste from the first, working IF-statement and now it works fine. I still don't get though what was my problem.

Comment: However it happened, glad you got it solved! I posted an answer on the presumption it was a stray input character.